# How to save spartacus auth information in session storage instead of local storage?

Tags: angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have a requirement that User must log into Spartacus app every time. After doing some research I got to know that if we use 'session storage' instead of using 'local storage' then this can be achievable.

Because when browser close the auth(spartacus⚿⚿auth) information will be deleted automatically.

Can anyone please give an idea how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Just curious, whats the difference between session and local storage?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: The most secure option is to avoid the persistence of the access token in the local storage or session storage. For more see https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage#browser-in-memory-scenarios

--

To change the persistence method to SessionStorage, you need to extend the `AuthStatePersistenceService` and overwrite its method `initSync()` (see [original implementation](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/3af6a0ea9d2bda7ae66b7b658c87bce6e61b974b/projects/core/src/auth/user-auth/services/auth-state-persistence.service.ts#L40-L51)). Inside the extended method, you need to pass explicitly the `storageType` (if omitted, it falls back to the default LocalStorage):

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CustomAuthStatePersistenceService extends AuthStatePersistenceService {
 
  initSync() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.statePersistenceService.syncWithStorage({
        key: this.key,
        state$: this.getAuthState(),
        onRead: (state) => this.onRead(state),
        storageType: StorageSyncType.SESSION_STORAGE, // <--- pass your storage type
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: AuthStatePersistenceService,
    useExisting: CustomAuthStatePersistenceService
  }
]
```